# EJB RESTful web service posting xml failure

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, jboss, ejb

I have problem with POSTing xml file to web service server. I was following this tutorial: [EJB WEB SERVICE TUTORIAL](http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/7/tutorial-restful-web-service-ejb-hibernate-jpa-jboss.html)
everything works except POSTing xml file. I am trying to do this via Poster chrome extension and get this error in JBoss console:

```
13:11:33,929 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed executing POST /customers: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: java.util.List<com.example.ejbrest.Customer> of content type: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:153) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:124) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:147) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

I was trying find solution on the internet but unfortunately nothing found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're posting a Customer List from a non structured format (text-plain). Resteasy will only be able to unmarshall from a structured format like xml,json. So your client app is the culprit in that case. If you really want to unmarshall from a String of character then you'll have to provide your own [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html).